# How to read sensor data in android bluetooth not single byte

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, bluetooth

I've read data from sensor in android app via bluetooth using following code

```
try {
                        int byteCount = inputStream.available();
                        if (byteCount > 0) {
                            count++;
                            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                            inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                            final String string = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    textView.append(string);
                                    textView.append("\n");    
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopThread = true;
                    }
```

This code read 10 as 1 and 0, So I want to read whole string . What will be required code for it?